# concatenate & Hex 256sha Hash a Signature

Tags: postman, sha256

I am trying to create a request in postman that pulls some parameters and puts them in the proper order and then hashes in sha256 hex. I understand I need to use a pre-request script but am struggling with what to use and how to get parameters in the script.

Example of the concatenate string - hex_sha256('[session:Key][session:Password][session:Sent][session:UnitAgencyTypeId][session:UnitName][session:UserInit][session:UserName][session:UserSub][session:Secret]')")]

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The script sandbox provided by Postman includes [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js), which can be used to compute SHA256 hashes. This can be done as follows:

```
var SHA256 = require('crypto-js').SHA256,
    hash = SHA256('your_content_goes_here');
```

As for the parameters, it is possible to use various parts of a request, as well as Postman variables to construct the input for your hashing needs. See https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference for a complete reference on all helpers provided by the Postman sandbox.

Comment: Here is what I am trying to emulate
https://text-share.com/view/17eee472#oDnp9LCMSEA1kvuuglieQh1lc5PtdJBW

But when I use this as a postman prescript I dont get the correct hash..
https://text-share.com/view/4fb6e6c2#spcpYWr9aFskrh5C6Qu8J9IUpserhfu6

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

here are some examples with sha:
https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-answers/request/18070393-87afb797-de5e-456b-b48a-15bf672bd1d3?tab=prscript

and here is my sample - i've added requestBody environment var (and use it in body tab) and use pre-srcipt to fill in the hexadecimal sha256 form & use other vars as my request body

```
var var_documentTypeId = 'xyz';
var var_code = '920961';
var var_date = '2023-12-18';
var var_type= 'phone';
var var_resultType = 'xls';

var sha256 = CryptoJS.algo.SHA256.create();
sha256.update(var_date+var_type+var_documentTypeId);
var sha256Hash = sha256.finalize().toString();

pm.environment.set("requestBody", JSON.stringify({
        "documentTypeId": var_documentTypeId,
        "code": var_code,
        "date": var_date ,
        "type": var_type,
        "hash": sha256Hash,
        "resultType": var_resultType
        }))

console.log("requestBody value: "+pm.environment.get("requestBody"))
```